# Inkscape: how to connect several lines and arcs into one continuous path?

Tags: graphics, inkscape, svg

I have a SVG document that is made of several lines and arcs that should form a continuous outline of some figure. How can I join all of those pieces into one path?

Comment: A picture would be really great for communicating the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Use Edit Path tool (F2)
- select each pair of nodes that should be glued into one node
- and use "Join selected endnodes" button on the toolbar (SHIFT+J)

Comment: Just a clarification: In order for this to work, the different "path objects" (lines/arcs etc.) in the document must first be combined into one and the same path object, if they aren't already. To achieve this, select all of the path objects to be combined, and press **Path** -> **Combine**

Comment: Yet another thing, which I had trouble figuring out. When the two end-nodes are close together, it can be difficult to select them both. It works if you click one path, click its end node, then hold down the shift key, click the other path, and click its end node.

Comment: You can use this technique for as many nodes as you want to join together. Just select all of them and click "Joint selected nodes" once. You don't have to do them one by one!

Comment: How to join an end point of a path to a mid point of another polygonal chain of lines? Imagine you got letter "V" and you want to join line "I" to its lowest point to form letter "Y". I cannot do it unless I break "V" into two separate paths.